# django_rest + angulardart

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, dart

Подскажите пожалуйста что не так? делаю по оф мануалу с сайта [оф.дока](https://angulardart.dev/guide/server-communication)

получаю такую ошибку "**Exception: Server error; cause: Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'**"
материал учебника был не много изменен, и расширен
advert.dart => hero.dart

```
class Advert {
  final int id;
  String title, owner, description, date;

  Advert(this.id, this.title, this.owner, this.description, this.date);

  factory Advert.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> advert) =>
      Advert(_toInt(advert['id']), advert['title'], advert['owner'],
        advert['description'], advert['date']);

  Map toJson() => {'id': id, 'title': title, 'owner': owner,
    'description': description, 'date': date};
}

int _toInt(id) => id is int ? id : int.parse(id);
```

advert_service.dart это hero_service.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

import 'advert.dart';

class AdvertService {
  static final _headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
  static const _advertsUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/adverts/';
  final Client _http;

  AdvertService(this._http);

  Future<List<Advert>> getAll() async {
    try {
      final response = await _http.get(_advertsUrl);
      final adverts = (_extractData(response) as List)
        .map((value) => Advert.fromJson(value))
        .toList();
      return adverts;
    } catch (e) {
      throw _handleError(e);
    }
  }

  Future<Advert> create(String title) async {
    try {
      final response = await _http.post(_advertsUrl,
          headers: _headers, body: json.encode({'title': title}));
      return Advert.fromJson(_extractData(response));
    } catch (e) {
      throw _handleError(e);
    }
  }

  dynamic _extractData(Response resp) => json.decode(resp.body)['data'];

  Exception _handleError(dynamic e) {
    print(e); // for demo purposes only
    return Exception('Server error; cause: $e');
  }
}
```

терминал PyCharm, говорит что запросы идут и код ответа 200 то есть тут вроде все ок
[09/Feb/2020 11:45:48] "GET /adverts/ HTTP/1.1" 200 492
[image: drf_api]

json

```
[{"id":1,"owner":"admin","title":"testing drf","description":"my one project django3+angulardart","date":"2020-02-05T19:35:42.235726+05:00"},{"id":2,"owner":"tester","title":"Реальные упыри","description":"Норм кинчик","date":"2020-02-06T22:29:57.479338+05:00"},{"id":3,"owner":"tester","title":"Создам сайт","description":"говнокодер напишет пахнущий код за ваши бабосики","date":"2020-02-06T22:30:30.832407+05:00"}]
```

Comment: нет метки "angulardart" поэтому использовал стандартный ангуляр

Comment: попробовал переписать все как в оф документации, без своих доп полей, ошибка та же...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dynamic _extractData(Response resp) => json.decode(resp.body)['data']; из это строки нужно удалить вот этот фрагмент ['data'] и все заработает, ну или править генерацию json в drf что бы он подставлял его туда, ибо ангуляр ждет json вида

```
{
  "data": [
    { "id": "1", "name": "Windstorm" },
    { "id": "2", "name": "Bombasto" },
    { "id": "3", "name": "Magneta" },
    { "id": "4", "name": "Tornado" }
  ]
}
```

если кто знает как в дрф сформировать такой json я с радостью почитаю.

Comment: Как так получилось, что в вопросе в json `"data"` отсутствовал, а в ответе появился?

Comment: django rest framework генерирует json без ключа "data", поэтому к ней в довесок была установлена дополнительная библиотека для генерации правильного формата json https://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html спецификация json https://jsonapi.org/

Comment: почему это нельзя было добавить в вопрос? И в django rest framework по умолчанию генерирует правильный json (_на то он rest framework_), а с помощью этого плагина вы только усложнили себе задачу...

Comment: потому что когда вопрос был задан стоял голый дрф, пакет формирующий json согласно спецификации был найден позже, суть всех движений была передать данные с джанги и получить их на фронте с помощью с Angulardart.  => цель достигнута

Comment: на проде такой трюк у вас бы не вышел...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так (только ничего не меняйте):

```
class Advert {
    int id;
    String owner;
    String title;
    String description;
    DateTime date;

    Advert({
        this.id,
        this.owner,
        this.title,
        this.description,
        this.date,
    });

    factory Advert.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Advert(
        id: json["id"],
        owner: json["owner"],
        title: json["title"],
        description: json["description"],
        date: DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "owner": owner,
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
        "date": date.toIso8601String(),
    };
}
```